# How many pages should be read to fulfil a simple index seek in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, common-table-expression

I am interested in understanding how Postgres reads pages from disk/cache when using an index.

Consider querying an indexed single-column table of integers:

```
select i 
into numbers
from generate_series(1, 200000) s(i);

create index idx on numbers(i);

explain (buffers, analyse)
select * from numbers where i = 456789; -- random row
```

This single index-only seek requires 3 page reads on this 200k row table (`Buffers: shared hit=3`):

```
Index Only Scan using idx on numbers  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=0 loops=1)
  Index Cond: (i = 456789)
  Heap Fetches: 0
  Buffers: shared hit=3
Planning Time: 0.043 ms
Execution Time: 0.022 ms
```

Is this expected? What do the 3 pages relate to? Is this simply the number of index pages which had to be read in order to traverse the B-Tree?

**Background**: I am trying to tune a recursive CTE which walks a linked-list structure stored in a single table as a parent-child relationship / adjacency-tree. The recursive section of the query is a very simple index seek similar to above. Each 'loop' of the recursive CTE results in 3 page reads (as per above), which is where the majority of the cost of the query lies. It may be impossible to make this any more efficient, but I was wondering if this could be improved somehow (currently ~30000 page reads for a 10k node chain, ~25ms cached).

Comment: Essentially it needs to read the root, branch and leaf node: https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/anatomy/the-tree

Comment: Thanks - I didn't appreciate that each node in the B-Tree is stored in a single page (as per https://rcoh.me/posts/postgres-indexes-under-the-hood/)

Comment: "which is where the majority of the cost of the query lies"  How did you determine that that is where the costs lies?  Are you talking about the cost estimate, or the actual run time cost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were lucky that autovacuum finished before you ran your query, otherwise it would have been 4 blocks.

Your query accessed the root node, an intermediate. node and a leaf node of index. There was no need to access a table block (`Heap Fetches: 0`), because

1. all the information is available in the index
2. the table's visibility map indicated that the table block was all-visible, so there was no necessity to consult the table block for the visibility information.

Comment: His query returned no rows, because it was outside of the range of the index.  If it had found a row, it would have had to consult either the VM or the table itself, leading to a 4th buffer access.